# Implementation of Organization Unit Identifier in peer organisation causes orderer panic and exit

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to add a new organisation to a peer org `Org1MSP`. I modified my `config.yaml` file which exist in `msp` directory. After modification of file, the content are mentioned below:

```
 OrganizationalUnitIdentifiers:
  - Certificate: cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: TEST
```

After modification, I have generated a `genesis.block` and `channel.tx`. I am using `docker` to bootstrap my network. The issue is when I bootstrap my network, orderer throws an error and exit. Logs of orderer are shown below:

```
orderer.example.com       | 2018-10-24 22:00:45.704 UTC [msp] satisfiesPrincipalInternalPreV13 -> DEBU 05b Checking if identity satisfies role [CLIENT] for Org1MSP
orderer.example.com       | 2018-10-24 22:00:45.704 UTC [msp] Validate -> DEBU 05c MSP Org1MSP validating identity
orderer.example.com       | 2018-10-24 22:00:45.704 UTC [msp] getCertificationChain -> DEBU 05d MSP Org1MSP getting certification chain
orderer.example.com       | 2018-10-24 22:00:45.704 UTC [msp] getCertificationChain -> DEBU 05e MSP Org1MSP getting certification chain
orderer.example.com       | 2018-10-24 22:00:45.704 UTC [msp] getCertificationChain -> DEBU 05f MSP Org1MSP getting certification chain
orderer.example.com       | 2018-10-24 22:00:45.705 UTC [orderer/commmon/multichannel] newLedgerResources -> PANI 060 Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: admin 0 is invalid: The identity is not valid under this MSP [Org1MSP]: could not validate identity's OUs: none of the identity's organizational units [[0xc4204e9ad0]] are in MSP Org1MSP
orderer.example.com       | panic: Error creating channelconfig bundle: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Consortiums sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: admin 0 is invalid: The identity is not valid under this MSP [Org1MSP]: could not validate identity's OUs: none of the identity's organizational units [[0xc4204e9ad0]] are in MSP Org1MSP
orderer.example.com       | 
orderer.example.com       | goroutine 1 [running]:
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc4200f0630, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x4f4
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc42017a1e0, 0x4, 0xe14c6d, 0x27, 0xc4204af958, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc42017a1e0, 0xe14c6d, 0x27, 0xc4204af958, 0x1, 0x1)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc42017a1e8, 0xe14c6d, 0x27, 0xc4204af958, 0x1, 0x1)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.(*Registrar).newLedgerResources(0xc4202725a0, 0xc420178e60, 0xc420178e60)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:256 +0x2ea
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel.NewRegistrar(0xea36a0, 0xc42000c3a0, 0xc4202567b0, 0xe9b060, 0x15a78b0, 0xc42017a2f0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/multichannel/registrar.go:142 +0x312
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.initializeMultichannelRegistrar(0xc420100580, 0xe9b060, 0x15a78b0, 0xc42017a2f0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:258 +0x250
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0xdf7a5a, 0x5, 0xc420100580)
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:96 +0x226
orderer.example.com       | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:75 +0x1d6
orderer.example.com       | main.main()
orderer.example.com       |     /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
orderer.example.com exited with code 2
```

I am using Hyperledger Fabric v1.3

complete logs can be found here: https://hastebin.com/ujiluvupox.php

Please let me know if you have any suggestion.
Any help/comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit to your `config.yaml` file in the MSP requires that all certificates issued by `cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem` has OU `TEST`.

If you inspect the admin cert in your MSP directory using something like:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in msp/admincerts/Admin\@org1.example.com-cert.pem | grep OU
```

You should be able to see the OUs of your certificate.  Most likely, your admin cert does not have this OU set, so it is not considered to be validly issued by your MSP (hence, the error setting up the MSP on bootstrap).

If you are bootstrapping your network using `cryptogen`, then you should edit your `crypto-config.yaml` file.  Under your org, add a `CA` element, with an `OrganizationalUnit: <YOUR_OU>` sub-element.  For instance:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    CA:
        OrganizationalUnit: TEST
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
```

I would also note, that if you are using `cryptogen` for bootstrapping your environment, then most likely requiring OUs inside of your MSP's `config.yaml` file is unnecessary.  Requiring specific OUs from your CA is most useful when attempting to integrate with an existing organization's CA server, which might issue certificates for other purposes, not all of which should be valid for use with Fabric.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know how to add OU to admin cert?

Comment: I've updated the post to show how OUs may be added if using cryptogen.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the issue is in the crypto material. If you enable NodeOUs in the MSP configuration, then you have to enable it also when generating the crypto material using cryptogen. Please, have a look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/a980c8f659051280c4e71f92fc6808ccff49e5d1/common/tools/cryptogen/main.go#L108 and https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/a980c8f659051280c4e71f92fc6808ccff49e5d1/common/tools/cryptogen/main.go#L192. Hope this helps.